# My scroll-react links aren't working on my react webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm setting scrolls with react-scroll but it isn't working for some reason. I checked the documentation but I can't see why this isn't working.

Here is my component where I'm setting the links:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Footer.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { Link } from 'react-scroll';

import {
    faFacebook,
    faTwitter,
    faInstagram,
} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

const footer = (props) => (
    <footer className={classes.Footer}>
        <ul className={classes.FooterLinks}>
            <li>
                <Link
                    to="navigation-bar"
                    smooth={true}
                    duration={1000}
                    className={classes.FooterLink}
                >
                    home
                </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link
                    to="about"
                    smooth={true}
                    duration={1000}
                    className={classes.FooterLink}
                >
                    about
                </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link
                    to="products"
                    smooth={true}
                    duration={1000}
                    className={classes.FooterLink}
                >
                    products
                </Link>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul className={classes.FooterIcons}>
            <li>
                <a
                    href="https://www.facebook.com/"
                    // target="_blank"
                    className={classes.FooterIcon}
                >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a
                    href="https://www.twitter.com"
                    // target="_blank"
                    className={classes.FooterIcon}
                >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTwitter} />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a
                    href="https://instagram.com"
                    // target="_blank"
                    className={classes.FooterIcon}
                >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram} />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p className={classes.Copyright}>
            copyright &copy; carlos suarez. all rights reserved
        </p>
    </footer>
);
```

Here is an example of the components and how Im setting Id:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './NavBar.css';
import NavbarMenuBurger from './NavbarMenuBurger/NavbarMenuBurger';
import NavbarCartIcon from './NavbarCartIcon/NavbarCartIcon';

const navBar = (props) => {
    return (
        <nav className={classes.Navbar} id="navigation-bar">
            <NavbarMenuBurger clicked={props.menuDrawerShowToTrue} />
            <h1 className={classes.HeaderTitle}>RAINBOW SODAS UK</h1>
            <NavbarCartIcon clicked={props.drawerShowToTrue} />
        </nav>
    );
};

export default navBar;
```

All the other components are set similarly.

Unfortunately, something isn't right and I can't figure out what this could be. I checked the DOM after the page is rendered and notice that the  tags are not showing the href property. Is this normal when using scroll-react?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a setting in my CSS that didn't allow scroll.

```
body,
html {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    /* width: 100%;
    height: 100%; */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```